# Sharing images with FileProvider doesn't work correctly

Tags: java, android, android-fileprovider

I am new to android development and I ran into problems sending files via FileProvider.
I am trying to send file from `storage` to other Apps on device. But unfortunately the file can't be attached in all apps.
Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="download" path="Download" />
</paths>
```

MainActivity.java

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
String filename = "cat.jpg";
String fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/" + filename;
File file = new File(fullPath);
Uri uriToImage = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToImage);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

This example works when I am sharing file from app's external storage, but I want to send the file from the internal storage of the device. Where could I go wrong?

Comment: Start by using a concrete MIME type, not a wildcard like `image/*`. Then, make sure that your `FileProvider` XML contains the roots that you need. Right now, your only root is for external storage (`external-path`).

Comment: What API are you targeting?

Comment: @CommonsWare I am trying to get the file `cat.jpg` from path `storage/emulated/0/Download`. As I understand, `external-path` "returns" the path `storage/emulated/0` or I am not correct?

Comment: @Graziano 31 api level

Comment: Use file.exists() and file.canRead() before you try to get an uri from FileProvider.

Comment: `path="Download"` Better: `path="."`

Comment: @blackapps So, after testing this methods, I saw that the file exists, but can't be read. That's strange

Comment: the required permissions are added to the manifest

Comment: No that is not strange on Android 11+ when the file is not created by your app.  You better use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to let the user select that file.

Comment: I fixed the problem with `requestPermissions()` method. this is a good decision?